# Difference between the Walsh and Hadamard transforms

Tags: linear-transformations

As far as I understand, the difference between the Walsh and Hadamard transforms is in the order of $\{-1,+1\}$ in the corresponding transformation matrices.

**Questions:**

1) What is the difference between the Walsh and Hadamard transforms?

2) Is it possible to calculate the Hadamard transform and then just change the order of the resulting coefficient vector to get the Walsh transform?

3) What is the purpose of a scaling factor? Could I just divide the resulting coefficient vector by the number of points?